# C# Read serial port value only if changed (weight machine)

Tags: c#, serial-port

```
private SerialPort _serialPort = null;

public WeightDisplay()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; 
    _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8);
    _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived);
    _serialPort.Open();
}
void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    txtWeight.Text = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
}
```

This code continuously gets values from weight machine connected to serial port and displays it in a textbox. Code works fine but I want to change the value of textbox if there is change in weight ie. if value returned by `ReadExisting()` differs from previous value.(I don't want the textbox to be fluctuated for no reason)

When I debug I get this value:

> "+  0.000 S\r+  0.000 S\r+  0.000 S\r+  0.000 S\r+  0.000 S\r+  0.000 S\r"

sometimes even big string

And my textbox displays  `"+  0.000"` (continuously blinking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   var newVal = _serialPort.ReadExisting();

   if(String.Compare(txtWeight.Text, newVal) != 0)
      txtWeight.Text = newVal;
}
```

You now only change the value of the TextBox if the value differs from the previous one.

**Update**
Since you get "+ 0.000 S\r+ 0.000 S\r+ 0.000 S\r+ 0.000 S\r+ 0.000 S\r+ 0.000 S\r" back but only need "+ 0.000" you can use regex to process your data:

```
void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   var expr = "\\+ [0-9]+\\.[0-9]+";
   var newVal = _serialPort.ReadExisting();

   MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(newVal, expr);

   if (mc.Count > 0)
   {
      if(String.Compare(txtWeight.Text, mc[0].Value) != 0)
         txtWeight.Text = mc[0].Value;
   }
}
```

This line only fetches the "+ 0.000" Values and put them in a collection `mc`

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(newVal, expr);
```

Now only the first element of this collection gets accessed with `mc[0].Value` (first "+ 0.000" value of the received data)

Comment: I am sorry ..I forgot to mention I have already tried above method but every time if condition evaluates to true and value of textbox changes.

When I debug I get this value in newVal variable="+  0.000 S\r+  0.000 S\r+  0.000 S\r+  0.000 S\r+  0.000 S\r+  0.000 S\r"

And my textbox displays  "+  0.000"

Comment: Is the TextBox supposed to show "+ 0.000" or is it supposed to show "+ 0.000 S\r+ 0.000 S\r+ 0.000 S\r+ 0.000 S\r+ 0.000 S\r+ 0.000 S\r" ?

Comment: Yeh..It suppose to show "+ 0.000". I think It's happening because of threading.

Comment: @AdilNaik Updated my answer, try this.

Comment: error in your code Unrecognized escape sequence (on first line) . I tried adding another backslash but getting error at if condition "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values"

Comment: @AdilNaik Sorry I forgot to escape the backslash , and you have to access the `Value` property of the item. I updated my answer.

Comment: You are great ..It worked :)   thanks alot
I made little changes to your code 
1) In regular exression there are two spaces after '+' 
var expr = "\\+  [0-9]+\\.[0-9]+";
2) Checked if mc has count >0
  if (mc.Count>0)
            {
                if (String.Compare(txtWeight.Text, mc[0].ToString()) != 0)
                    txtWeight.Text = mc[0].ToString();
            }

Update your answer