# RS232 How to read weight from weight scale base each bytes

Tags: c#, serial-port

Dear all my friends i have software that read the weight from weight indicator i worked with many weight indicator that connect to scales always i read weight with this option of serial `serialport1.ReadExisting();`
after that i play with string but this time i have new weight indicator that each time read many string in one line from indicator always its changed the shape its difficult for me to get correct weight its sample of readExisting(); but my target is only 130  `“              "    0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rip0   130     0\rix0   130     0\rix0   120     0\rix0   120     0\rix0   120     0\rix0   120     0\rix0   120     0\rix0   120     0\rix0   120     0\rix0   120     0\rix0   120     0\rix0   120     0\rix0   120     0\rix0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\rip0   120     0\r"

”` 
also it has some another char that you can see [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcQEh.jpg) and some time in bad format now my question is that how to read in standard format that the company says this is the manual i dont know how read the corect bytes from serial port if you know please help me this is the manual of weight indicator Flintec FT-11
[FLintec FT-11 Data output manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY0G5.png)

Comment: ReadExisting() is rarely used correctly.  You need to set the SerialPort.NewLine property to "\r" and now you can use ReadLine().  Which ensures you always get a single complete measurement, parse it with String.SubString() and Int32.Parse().

Comment: @HansPassant how to set the serialPort.NewLine Property to "\r"

Comment: The only possible thing you could do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: dear @HansPassant i try it many times in many different i can only get the 120 but cant fix in tex box its always change it my problem is just like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080188/c-sharp-read-serial-port-value-only-if-changed-weight-machine?rq=1

Comment: dear @HansPassant its fixed thanks allot its work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output you posted it is clear that the device sends 8 bytes of data for each packet.  So you need [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] so you need bytes 3, 4. So what you need to do first is to set the RecievedByteThreshold property for your serial port object to 8 bytes. Then use SerialDataRecieved event. The event would be triggered only when it recieves  up to 8 bytes. Then create a byte array of size 8 that would help you hold the 8 byte data lets call it Data [8]. Then in your SerialDataRecieved event handler call the method `SerialPort.Read(Data, 0, 1)`. Then you should have your data array equal to the 8 byte that your weight device is sending per data packet.  So you can easily get the 2nd and 3rd element in the array. So you weigut would be `Data[2]×10+Data [3]`.

> [you can checkout the serialport class here for more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can you please write this code for me to  check i cant understand please write i example

Comment: Dear @ozioma  please explain the code more i creat like this   byte[] data = new byte[8]            serialport1.read(data,0,1)       string k = Data[2]×10+Data [3].tostring();

Comment: ReceivedByteThreshold is very bad advice, it prevents proper synchronization with the data and only ever works by accident.